# Define an emacs command that calls another emacs command (preserving interactive stuff)

Tags: emacs, command, elisp, interactive

How can I define an emacs command X that does something and then calls another emacs command Y and also copying the interactive interface of the command Y too?

I want to define an altenative version of query-replace with temporarilly toggled value of case-fold-search:

```
(defun alt-query-replace (a b c d e)
  (interactive)
  (let ((case-fold-search (not case-fold-search))
    (query-replace a b c d e)))
```

This doesn't work. When I call alt-query-replace, it says "wrong number of arguments". I want the interactive interface of alt-query-replace to be the same as query-replace. Do I need to inspect the source code of query-replace or is there a general approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use call-interactively:

```
(defun alt-query-replace ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((case-fold-search (not case-fold-search)))
    (call-interactively 'query-replace)))
```

Comment: Will that code magically pass all args through to `query-replace` as though it were called directly?

Answer (score 5):

You may advise the original function, if you want to modify its behavior instead of calling a separate function.

From [chapter 17.3 Around-Advice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Around_002dAdvice.html) of the GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual:

> Around-advice lets you “wrap” a Lisp
>   expression “around” the original
>   function definition.
>
> ```
>  (defadvice foo (around foo-around)
>    "Ignore case in `foo'."
>    (let ((case-fold-search t))
>      ad-do-it))
> ```

In your case, you can write:

```
(defadvice query-replace (around alt-query-replace (from-string to-string &optional delimited start end))
    (let ((case-fold-search (not case-fold-search)))
      ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'query-replace)
```

Comment: I've noticed folks having `ad-activate` done separately from the original advice, but you can have activate in the original line `around alt-query-replace (...) activate`.