# Simulate minibuffer input in Emacs

Tags: emacs, minibuffer

I'm looking for a way to simulate minibuffer input. So, **some-func** takes some input from the minibuffer and does something with it. The problem is that I have to call **some-func** from some other function **calling-func** and I need to do it interactively so I cant just pass an argument.

```
(defun some-func (arg)
  (interactive "*sEnter something: ")
  ;; Do something with arg
  )

(defun calling-func ()
  (call-interactively 'some-func)
  ;; Type to minibuffer
  )
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be interesting to explore why you need to call the other function interactively... but that's not what you asked.

Here's an example of "calling" a function interactively and sending text to the minibuffer.  You just use Emacs keyboard macros:

```
(defun my-call-find-file (something)
  "An example of how to have emacs 'interact' with the minibuffer
use a kbd macro"
  (interactive "sEnter something:")
  (let ((base-vector [?\M-x ?f ?i ?n ?d ?- ?f ?i ?l ?e return]))
    ;; create new macro of the form
    ;; M-x find-file RET <userinput> RET
    (execute-kbd-macro (vconcat base-vector 
                                (string-to-vector something) 
                                (vector 'return)))))
```

The relevant documentation are [Keyboard Macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keyboard-Macros.html) and [Functions for Vectors](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Vector-Functions.html#Vector-Functions).

Comment: I guess I can use something like this. I'll try it out a bit. You ask why I need to call it interactively. I don't *need* to. But it's better. I'm trying some testing. So I want to simulate a user. I can just call the function, but that wouldn't be how the user would interact with it.

Comment: Well, the kbd macro is essentially how the user interacts with it.  It's just a stream of key presses being sent to Emacs.

Comment: The more you learn about Emacs, the more you realize how brilliant it is. Sometimes you doubt if something is possible and it always turns out that it is.

Answer (score 1):

I've been mixing around with the macro stuff. Consider these different cases:

1) When the whole vector is all together it works!

```
(defun a ()
  (interactive)
  (execute-kbd-macro [?\M-x ?l ?i ?n ?u ?m ?- ?m ?o ?d ?e return]))
```

2) But when I split it up, it doesn't.

```
(defun a ()
  (interactive)
  (b)
  (c)
  (d))

(defun b ()
  (execute-kbd-macro [?\M-x]))

(defun c ()
  (execute-kbd-macro [?l ?i ?n ?u ?m ?- ?m ?o ?d ?e]))

(defun d ()
  (execute-kbd-macro (vector 'return)))
```

3) Running it as a string does not work either.

```
(defun a ()
  (interactive)
  (execute-kbd-macro (string-to-vector "M-x linum-mode RET")))

(defun a ()
  (interactive)
  (execute-kbd-macro "M-x linum-mode RET"))
```

I actually need to chain the events together. So, do I need to use **vconcat** on vectors then?

Comment: Yes, to get what you're trying for, you do.  Which is why my solution had the 'vconcat call.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
(defun calling-func ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'some-func)
  ;; Type to minibuffer
  )
```

That is, use an empty `interactive` specification, and pick up the transitive specification via `call-interactively`.

If that was in fact what you were asking for, there's a nearly identical answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593366/define-an-emacs-command-that-calls-another-emacs-command-preserving-interactive/1593659#1593659).

Comment: I don't think this will help me since I still would have to type something and I can't do that. I have to simulate that. See comment to Trey Jackson for reason.

Comment: Ah, I thought that you wanted `calling-func` to behave with the exact same interactive interface as `some-func`, without specifying its interactive interface again.